# codeigniter multiple checkbox values associated with text

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter-3

I have a page where people can add in text and next to it have a checkbox. The checkbox should be associated with the inputted text. I also have a button to add extra textfields and checkboxes controlled with javascript. The main issue is that I only recieve the "1" and not the not checked. Therefore I am unable to rightly populate the arrays needed to write to the database.

```php
<h2 class="display-4 text-center pb-3"><?php echo $this->lang->line('titel'); ?></h2>
<section class="d-flex justify-content-center">
<?php 
    $attributes = array('class' => 'col-md-8'); 
    echo form_open('create_s460/s460', $attributes); 
?>

    <div class="form-group" id="extend_field">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-7 col-xs-13">
                <label for="ingediendDoor"><?php echo $this->lang->line('melding'); ?></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-6 text-center">
                <label for="ingediendDoor"><?php echo $this->lang->line('verzender'); ?></label>            
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <label for="ingediendDoor"><?php echo $this->lang->line('voeg_meer_toe'); ?></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-7 col-xs-13">
                <input type="text" name="s460Melding[][s460_input_melding]" placeholder="<?php echo $this->lang->line('melding'); ?>" class="form-control name_list" required="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-6 text-center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="s460verzender[][s460_input_verzender]" value="1" checked>          
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $this->lang->line('voeg_meer_toe'); ?></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="<?php echo $this->lang->line('submit'); ?>" /> 
    </div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){      
      var i=1;  

      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#extend_field').append('<div class="row" id="row'+i+'"><div class="form-group col-md-7 col-xs-13"><input type="text" name="s460Melding[][s460_input_melding]" placeholder="<?php echo $this->lang->line('melding'); ?>" class="form-control name_list" required="" /></div><div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-6 text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="s460verzender[][s460_input_verzender]" value="1" checked></div><div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xs-6"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></div></div>');
      });

      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  

    });
</script>
```

```php
/**
     * Krijg de gegevens voor de S460
     */
    private function collectS460Data()
    {
        if(!empty($this->input->post('s460Melding')))
        {
            $meldingen = $this->input->post('s460Melding');          
        }
        if(!empty($this->input->post('s460verzender')))
        {
            $verzendingen = $this->input->post('s460verzender');          
        }

        if(count($meldingen) < count($verzendingen))
        {
            array_shift($verzendingen);
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($meldingen); $i++)
        {
            $data[$i]['s460_input_melding'] = $meldingen[$i]['s460_input_melding'];
            $data[$i]['s460_input_verzender'] = $verzendingen[$i]['s460_input_verzender'];
        }

        // return $data;
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($meldingen);
        var_dump($verzendingen);
        var_dump($data);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

What i am trying to do is get the inputed melding (message text) and the inputed verzender checkbox. Togheter to then add it to the database. If anyone has a solution that might work i would be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

As the issues where bigger then expected I decided to use a different approach. Using radio buttons and a toggle switch look I managed to receive the same result without all the hassle of using a checkbox. As it is a checkbox sends threw 1 or nothing. The nothing is good if you have a specific name for a checkbox and can check. But if you have a undefined amount it becomes cluttered and unmanageable.

```php
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-6 text-center switch-field">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-0" name="s460verzender[0][s460_input_verzender]" value="1" checked/>
    <label for="radio-0"><?php echo $this->lang->line('verzender'); ?></label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-00" name="s460verzender[0][s460_input_verzender]" value="0"/>
    <label for="radio-00"><?php echo $this->lang->line('ontvanger'); ?></label>
</div>
```

To manage all the different radio buttons all you have to do is add a value in between `name="s460verzender[   value in here     ][s460_input_verzender]"`. I opted to use the number generator in the javascript part to manage it all.

But now you either get 1 or 0.